# Extract blocks of certain number from array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector and I would like to extract all the ***4***'s from it:

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4]
```

so that I will get 4 vectors or a cell containing the 4 blocks of ***4***'s:

```
[4 4], [4], [4 4 4], [4 4 4 4]
```

Thanks!

Comment: feels like idx=find(x==4) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create cells from the appropriate ranges using [**`arrayfun`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4];     
x = [0, x, 0]; D = diff (x==4);               % pad array and diff its mask
A = find (D == 1); B = find (D == -1);        % find inflection points
out = arrayfun (@ (a,b) {x(a+1 : b)}, A, B)   % collect ranges in cells
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to the answer I was preparing :-)

Comment: hahah, thanks for saying this, I'll take it as evidence my programming approach is finally starting to mature then, heheh :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty fast, using [**`accumarray`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
X = 4;

%// data
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4]

%// mask all 4
mask = x(:) == X

%// get subs for accumarray
subs = cumsum( diff( [0; mask] ) > 0 )

%// filter data and sort into cell array
out = accumarray( subs(mask), x(mask), [], @(y) {y} )
```

Comment: Interesting approach. BTW, you can remove the `//` from the comments :) We have basic MATLAB highlighting now!

Comment: @rayryeng wow! I'm not here that often anymore. I even use `//` for my own code now :D

Comment: :D I know.  My employer was wondering why I kept doing that with my MATLAB comments lol.

Comment: Nice use of accumarray. Also, nice "linking to the manual" hack, I'm totally stealing it for my own answer, hahah :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou it's a great way to link to documentation to show the user how to use the function for later. I've been doing it since I stated answering.

Comment: @rayryeng hahah, I know, but I shamelessly stole the exact formatting too :p  I totally meant to acknowledge him on my edit, but stackoverflow 'merges' nearby edits together and won't let me just change the title of an edit ¬_¬

Answer (score 1):

with regionprops we can set  property PixelValues so the function returns 1s instead of 4s

```
x = [1 1 1 4 4 5 5 4 6 1 2 4 4 4 9 8 4 4 4 4]
{regionprops(x==4,'PixelValues').PixelValues}
```

if we set property PixelIdxList the function returns  a cell of indices of 4s:

```
{regionprops(x==4,'PixelIdxList').PixelIdxList}
```

Update(without image processing toolbox):
this way we can get number of elements of each connected components:

```
c = cumsum(x~=4)
h=hist(,c(1):c(end));
h(1)=h(1)+~c(1);
result = h(h~=1)-1
```

Comment: This requires the image processing toolbox. Do you have a solution that doesn't rely on a toolbox?

Comment: I tested it in GNU Octave. other solutions (cellfun , loop) are slower than this.

Comment: That is certainly true. Still a very interesting approach.  I'll +1 this.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx=find(x==4);
for (i= 1:length(idx)) 
   if (i==1 || idx(i-1)!=idx(i)-1)if(i!=1) printf(",") endif; printf("[") endif;
   printf("4");
   if (i<length(idx)&&idx(i+1)==idx(i)+1) printf(",") else printf("]") endif
endfor
```

Note this won't give the actual vectors, but it will give the output you wanted. The above is OCtave code. I am pretty sure changing endfor and endif to end would work in MAtlab, but without testing in matlab, I am not positive.[edited in light of comment]

Comment: (just pointing out this is meant to be on matlab specifically, so no `endfor`)

Comment: sorry, I have Octave here. tT worked in that. But replacing the endif and endfor with end  ought to work.

Comment: you could be really evil and collect the statements using `sprintf` instead, and then `eval` at the end >:D `idx=find(x==4);
s = "";
for (i= 1:length(idx)) 
   if (i==1 || idx(i-1)!=idx(i)-1)
     if(i!=1) 
       s = [s sprintf(",")];
     endif; 
     s = [s sprintf("[")];
   endif;
   s = [s sprintf("4")];
   if (i<length(idx)&&idx(i+1)==idx(i)+1) 
     s = [s sprintf(",")];
   else 
     s = [s sprintf("]")];
   endif
endfor
Out = eval(["{" s "}"]) % evil!`

Comment: I like that. I guess one person's evil is another's elegant :)